# Choppy/Stuttering audio using minim on rpi

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi, processing, playback

I seem to be having a great amount of trouble trying to get concurrent (four in this case) audio files to play back in Processing3 on a raspberry pi. The audio ends up being very choppy, stuttering every half second or so consistently until I decide to shut it off.

I've also tried one audio file playing back just to check and it starts off very choppy for a good few seconds, before only becoming slightly choppy (consistently a stutter every ~5 seconds or so).

My first attempts was with the Minim library, but I've also tried the Beads library as well (this fails entirely on the pi, freezes until an "out of memory error" is displayed). I've also attempted Processing's Sound library, but couldn't get this one to first work on my dev machine (windows 7 and java 1.8 just crashes) and doesn't seem to be supported on ARM.

The files I'm attempting to play are currently mp3 files, though I have control over this and have tried wav as well as mp3 with a few different bit rates (48, 96, 128, 192 kbps). I can't hear any differences no matter the file type I try.

The rpi I am using is a B+, initially running wheezy but now I've migrated to a fresh image of jessie-lite (manually installed what was needed to run Processing3, including java 1.8). The memory allocation is split 50% (256mb to gpu).

This my code on how I'm playing sounds right now using Minim:

```
import ddf.minim.*;

private final String TYPE = ".mp3";
private final String MUSIC_A = "01-09_mixdown";
private final String MUSIC_B = "10-18_mixdown";
private final String MUSIC_C = "19-27_mixdown";
private final String MUSIC_D = "28-35_mixdown";
private final String SOUND_LOCATION = "sounds/";

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer[] audioPlayers= new AudioPlayer[4];

// have played with this a few times, trying 512, 1024, and 2048 as well as leaving this out altogether (default was 2048 I think)
int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

float changeRate = 0.05;
float[] volumes;

void setup(){
    this.frameRate = 24;
    size(320, 240, P2D);

    minim = new Minim(this);
    audioPlayers[0] = minim.loadFile(SOUND_LOCATION + MUSIC_A + TYPE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    audioPlayers[1] = minim.loadFile(SOUND_LOCATION + MUSIC_B + TYPE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    audioPlayers[2] = minim.loadFile(SOUND_LOCATION + MUSIC_C + TYPE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    audioPlayers[3] = minim.loadFile(SOUND_LOCATION + MUSIC_D + TYPE, BUFFER_SIZE);

    volumes = new float[4];
    volumes[0] = 0.5;
    volumes[1] = 0.5;
    volumes[2] = 0.5;
    volumes[3] = 0.5;

    audioPlayers[0].loop();
    audioPlayers[1].loop();
    audioPlayers[2].loop();
    audioPlayers[3].loop();

    println("Playing now");
}

void draw(){
    // no drawing for this test
}
```

Finally, attempts to play audio outside of processing are successful (no issues using omxplayer).

Wondering what else I could try next, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to get some kind of audio playing properly given the library and environment:

My guess is the mp3 decoder is just very processing intensive. I could be wrong, but the difference in one file vs four mp3 files leads me to this conclusion (even if both results were choppy/stuttering).

Instead I got wav files to work.

They weren't working before as it turns out I was exporting them with 32 floating bit depth which I guess is not compatible with minim. 16 bit depth appears to work fine and playing multiple files simultaneously seems to have no major issue.